# Improving reading BQ data from inside of a transformation in apache beam - Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an apache beam pipeline that I submit to google cloud Dataflow.
My use case is as follows:

- I have a BQ table A that I read using Beam IO native connector to a pcollection
- I pass the pcollection to a transformation where I need to check for every element if the current it exists in a table B in BQ. I couldn't find a way to execute the query with native Apache beam, that's why I used the BQ python library by google
- After that I save my desired result to BQ table C using beam IO connector

My approach is working good, but It's costly. For a table A of 150k records for example, it takes at least 15 days of processing, which is wrapped into 2 hours with 475 workers in google dataflow. I know that the main cause of the high cost and the long execution time is the SQL queries that I'm submitting for each element from inside the transformation, because it takes time.

Have you guys faces an issue like this before? or do you know an improvement that I can invent in my code to reduce costs?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A side solution that is simple and elegant (I don't know how I couldn't think about it)

Instead of passing directly Table A to the beam job to be processed, I create a new table A2 that is a result of left join between table A and table B.

So the data that I request from the workers throw SQL queries, will be already existing in the input data of the Job (table A2)

This saved a lot of computing resources